# PhpStorm. Failed to collect files. Could not resolve file "sftp://***"

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, phpstorm, sftp

I rent a server for a year now and do some minor projects/tests on it remotely with my friend.
~A month ago started encountering problem while trying to fetch new project in PhpStorm. I setup new SSH connection, configure SFTP connection - it starts downloading files and after 1-3 mins it throws this error.

Tried to google across the internet and saw several topics on official JetBrains website and here on StackOverflow but none of them helped me specifically as mostly they were related to already synced project or server side settings which at first glance seems alright.

A bit of additional info - aside of PhpStorm I'm using PuTTY and WinSCP and SSH connections in both of them are pretty much stable for hours.
Also my friend is using VS Code instead, his projects are usually synced fine but after some short time it has failed connection which leads to another problem after success reconnect - indexing process each time which completely overload the server for several mins.

**For now what was done:**

1. On server `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file I added these lines:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 720
```

2. In PhpStorm SSH connection configuration set `KeepAlive` time for 30 secs (tried greater/lower values and ratios)

Here is a piece of PhpStorm log that might be related:

```
2023-10-29 10:36:50,196 [ 291714] SEVERE - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Ubuntu - PhpStorm 2023.2.3  Build #PS-232.10072.32
2023-10-29 10:36:50,196 [ 291714] SEVERE - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Ubuntu - JDK: 17.0.8.1; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-10-29 10:36:50,196 [ 291714] SEVERE - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Ubuntu - OS: Windows 10
2023-10-29 10:36:50,199 [ 291717]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Ubuntu - Watcher terminated with exit code -1
2023-10-29 10:36:50,199 [ 291717]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.i.l.FileWatcher - [Ubuntu] File watcher failed repeatedly and has been disabled
2023-10-29 10:38:46,836 [ 408354]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-10-29 10:39:59,789 [ 481307]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Forced closing file system of sftp://***:22/ in @70d85d60
2023-10-29 10:39:59,790 [ 481308]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Forced closing file system of sftp://***:22/ in @7e11867f
2023-10-29 10:39:59,790 [ 481308]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Forced closing file system of sftp://***:22/ in @cd5a3c4
2023-10-29 10:40:15,208 [ 496726]   INFO - STDOUT - 
2023-10-29 10:40:15,293 [ 496811]   INFO - #c.i.e.w.WslDistributionManager - Fetched WSL distributions: [(Ubuntu, version=2), (Debian, version=2)] ("C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --list --verbose" done in 59 ms)
2023-10-29 10:40:15,440 [ 496958]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Debian - The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed. 

2023-10-29 10:40:15,440 [ 496958] SEVERE - #c.i.o.v.i.w.W.Debian - Illegal watcher command: ' E r r o r   c o d e :   W s l / S e r v i c e / C r e a t e I n s t a n c e / C r e a t e V m / H C S _ E _ S E R V I C E _ N O T _ A V A I L A B L E
```

Regarding log I'm also not sure that these lines about WSL are actually related as exactly several months ago I disabled it on my Windows.

3. Also tried to work around with `.ssh/config` file on my local machine side and added these lines:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInternal 30
    TCPKeepAlive no
```

It didn't help but I have doubts that this format of SSH settings was correct as while working locally on my work project and when tried to connect with console to work project by SSH it failed with saying that `.ssh/config` file is broken. But sadly haven't found any additional info so far.

**I'm about to try to reinstall server from scratch** and I would already do that if I knew it would help 100%. But I have doubts and feel like it might not help or even if it help what will I do when I encounter the same issue after a while again. So this is not the right decision.

Also another known "solution" is to create zip file of a project, grab it to local, deploy and then sync with remote server with deploy settings. It would work for me and for long term projects, but we often create small clear projects with framework and repeating this process all over again is a pain honestly. Plus it will not fix the issue that my friend encounters with VS Code.

Thanks to anyone who pays attention to this topic in advance.

Comment: I doubt that WSL error has something to do with the issue here. What you may try is to increase a log level for deployment & SSH subsystems to get more details.

To increase it, add the following lines (as a separate lines) to the "Help > Diagnostic Tools > Debug Log Settings":
#com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment
#com.intellij.ssh

Comment: @duck_in_hat these lines are already there. Maybe if i share full log somehow it may help? I can clear logs, initiate another error and share the log

Comment: @instant Use `Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...` within the IDE to make a Support ticket where you can privately provide all required information (be it log files, test project, an access to a test environment etc etc). This would be the best way.